# “How To Tag” character list omits accented letters

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, user-interface

When entering the tags on a question, the “How To Tag” help box mentions

> tag characters: [a-z 0-9 + # - .]

On this site, diacritics are allowed, so this should be something like

> tag characters: a–z àâçéèêëîïôœûü 0–9 +-.#

(I omitted characters that are unlikely to appear in a French tag name) or keep it simple:

> tag characters: letters digits +-.#

I think this bug is present on all language sites.

---

Quand on entre les étiquettes d'une question, la boîte d'aide « *How To Tag* » indique

> tag characters: [a-z 0-9 + # - .]

Sur notre site, les lettres accentuées sont autorisées, donc il faudrait écrire quelque chose comme

> tag characters: a–z àâçéèêëîïôœûü 0–9 +-.#

(je n'ai mentionné que les lettres qui ont une chance d'apparaître dans une étiquette en français) ou pour faire simple :

> tag characters: letters digits +-.#

(Ou « caractères autorisés : lettres chiffres +-.# » mais c'est un autre débat.)

Comment: Yup; this has come up on [meta.pt](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4223/texto-caracteres-da-tag-na-como-fazer-uma-tag-est%C3%A1-quebrado) as well; the fun question is: *what is the clearest phrasing?*. And (see Gabe's comment) - is it already correct even while omitting accents? I would be against exhaustive, because in reality: they aren't exhaustive (also: it is ugly). "alphanumeric", "letters digits", etc are possibilities.

Comment: @MarcGravell As I wrote on meta.pt.so: when I see “a-z”, I understand that accents cannot be used. Since an exhaustive list is neither possible nor desirable, I think writing “letters” makes sense. “Alphanumeric” isn't a common word for nontechnical audiences. Also I think the brackets should be removed: programmers may understand them as meaning “the characters inside”, but for people who don't know regexp syntax, it looks like the brackets are allowed characters.

Comment: in reality, the list is actually much  wider than that; going with "letters digits + # - ." for now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be clearer next build.